# javafx : how to show String in TableView

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

i want to show some strings in TableView in javafx but when im adding them to the table i can select them which means they are added but it wount display the Strings its just like there is null in them .

i've used the TableView before to show a property of an object this way :

```
repositoriesColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("name"));
```

and after viewing that i would have see the names . i know how it works this way .

but this time i have an ArrayList and there is no object to use the refelection . there is just Strings and i cant get any property of to be shown . i tried do to it this way but it wouldn't help:

```
repositoriesColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<String, String>("string"));
```

here is the declatations of columns :

```
@FXML
public javafx.scene.control.TableColumn repositoriesColumn;

@FXML
public javafx.scene.control.TableColumn ownerColumn;
```

and i couln't find anything similar to that in the internet , what should i do ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but you can wrap you string in a property and add it.  Something like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class SampleApp extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch (args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Collection<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("String1");
        list.add("String2");
        list.add("String3");
        list.add("String4");
        list.add("String5");
        list.add("String6");

        ObservableList<String> details = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);

        TableView<String> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<String, String> col1 = new TableColumn<>();
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(col1);

        col1.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleStringProperty(data.getValue()));
        tableView.setItems(details);

        StackPane sp = new StackPane(tableView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(sp);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answere . i did the above but im getting the following error : Error:(146, 98) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getValue()
  location: variable data of type java.lang.Object

Comment: Can you post what your code is exactly?  The code above does work and provides a list of values in your table.  Do you have the Lambda portion of the code?  "data -> " - have you tried to run this example?  If you have tried to run it as is, can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: Is getValue() method still available? My IDE can't resolve that method

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question, asking for help on two columns